# Suggestions for GUI of a multiledia messaging application in J2ME

Tags: java, user-interface, textbox, textfield, java-me

We have developed a messaging application in j2me which adds text message, gets pictures from gallery and attaches them to the message etc and sends it over to a server after encryption, i.e. the client wants the messages to be encrypted. The app is ready but the only problem is that the GUI of the app looks miserable compared to the GUI of native messaging application on Nokia phones.

Our GUI consists of a texfield for adding recipients i.e. the user clicks "options" to "add recipients" and is taken to a new form where contacts are shown. but the textfield is not in one line (like in case of native app). Also, we need the user to input the text message in a textField since we cannot have textbox inside a form (but the native app has a textbox as well as a textField ). Are there any ways to achieve such GUIs (one-line textfields, textbox like thing inside a form)?

I hope you all understand what I mean, any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks and regards,
Ashish.

Comment: Instead of developing on a form, try developing the app in canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are using `javax.microedition.lcdui`. Have you looked at [LWUIT](http://lwuit.dev.java.net)? It's swing like and some nice features.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your responses. I developed a custom item and all the problems are solved. LWUIT was interesting to know.

Thanks,
Ashish.